# Why you need to say "Она" in sentence "Она пошла"?

Tags: лексикон

If you'r being asked `-Где она?`, you need to say `-Она пошла`, but `Она` was already said, it's clear that you talk about her, why you need to use that again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do you need to use Я with verbs in the present tense?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/why-do-you-need-to-use-%d0%af-with-verbs-in-the-present-tense)

Comment: You may omit it, but with a second Она it will look better. Same as in english: Where is she? She is gone.

Comment: @crea7or In English it cannot be omitted unless it's the second verb of the same sentence.

Comment: @ Alenanno Why not? I can easily imagine a dialogue like:

Comment: - Where's she? - Gone!

Answer (score 4):

In the example you gave, it is **not** strictly necessary to repeat *Она*. As you correctly pointed out, the previous sentence is already speaking of *она*, therefore it is clear what the conversation is about.

> Где она?
>   Ушла
>
> Как она тебе?
>   Хороша!

There is nothing wrong with using *она* for the second time, however in the examples above it would only make sentences sound worse, not better.

You are much more likely to actually **need** to use it where there's more than one (feminine or otherwise) subject (e.g. the *она* you're talking about plus somebody/something else).  For example,

> Где она сейчас, где ее мать?
>   Она - в Лондоне.
>   (This means, *she is in London*, but I am not saying anything about her mother.  On the other hand, saying simply *In London* would mean that they both are in London.)
>
> Где она со своим другом? (Note that a better usage would be *где они*.)
>   Она ушла.
>   (She's gone, but I am not saying anything about her friend.)

Comment: I insist that this one is duplicate of http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/why-do-you-need-to-use-Я-with-verbs-in-the-present-tense

Comment: @shabunc Please explain how it is a duplicate.

Comment: no offense, I like your answer, it's just that this question is about "why should we use personal pronoun when all information needed is  already provided by the verb form"? And this is exactly what was that question about.

Comment: Now I see I'm probably wrong, this is slightly different case.

Answer (score 0):

If you answer the question with -Она пошла, you should specify where to, and that is obligatory. If you say 'она ушла', then the usage of the pronoun is arbitrary; that is, you don't always have to use it.

Strange enough, here I might agree with 'shabunc'; this being a partially duplicating question.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note, which, however, could still serve as an answer. The thing is "пошла" could as well be a verb in the imperative mood, that is, it could mean "Start walking!", "Go!", "Forward!", "Go forward!" when applied to a woman. So, if we imagine that the one who asked the question "Где она?" is a female, then the answer "Пошла" in this case would simply mean something like "Start walking and don't ask stupid questions!" or "Start walking, and no talking!" (of course, in the written speech "Пошла" would probably be written with an exclamation mark: "Пошла!"). So, to avoid that connotation, adding "Она" before "пошла" will make sure that the one who is answering is still speaking in the indicative mood, not in the imperative one, which means that he or she is still answering the question and not giving any commands.